# Homomorphism between cyclic groups is determined by an integer

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Suppose $G$ is a cyclic group and $f \colon G \rightarrow G$ is any homomorphism. Show there is an integer $n$ such that $f(\gamma) = \gamma^n$ for all $\gamma \in G$. Show that if $G$ is infinite, then $n$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

Here is my solution:

We know the image of a group homomorphism is a subgroup $H$ of $G$. So $H$ is also a cyclic group. Suppose $a$ is is a generator of $G$, then there is an integer $n$, such that $a^n$ is a generator of $H$. Because homomorphism between cyclic groups maps generator to generator (I know this result but how to prove?). Then the first statement is obvious. When $G$ is infinite, this is unique.

EDIT: Sorry for deleting this question before, because I didn't post my solution in the first version of this question.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry, updated

Comment: Please update your notation. $e$ is the neutral element.

Comment: @Shaun The OP is using $H$ to represent the image of the homomorphism.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you, @J126. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: It's not that's there's an integer, $n$, such that $a^n$ is a generator.  The image of $a$ is a generator of the image, because $a$ generates $G$.  You use the properties of homomorphisms to prove that.  Also, $a^n$ is not an element of $H$, but $f(a^n)$ is.